# Size div to it's content without "width: fit-content"

Tags: html, css, width

Here is a code snippet with the exact behavior I would like to replicate.

I want to add an effect to the title when the mouse is hovering anywhere on the link.

```css
.link {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

.link .title {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: fit-content;
}

.link:hover .title {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Subtitle that is usually longer than the title</div>
</a>
```

**My problem:** I can't use the `width: fit-content;` CSS rule as it is not supported by IE.
If you try running this snippet in IE, you will see something like this: [image (on imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwjxF.png)

**My question:** How can I make sure the `.title` div always fits its's content without using `width: fit-content`?

Comment: Does using ``display: inline-block`` in ``.title`` div solve it for you?

Comment: You can use span or just set display:inline for the title div without mentioning any width property.

Comment: Thx for your quick answeres! In my real use case, I have to use `display: flex` on `.title` to manage its content. There fore I can't really use your solutions ...

Comment: @benzi11, what answer do you expect if you have not posted your real case? =))
Try `inline-flex`.

Comment: @KoshVery You are right, I should have posted more details. I was trying to minimize my post length.

Comment: @KoshVery `display: inline-flex` worked like a charm